# Race detection in table driven test

Tags: unit-testing, go, concurrency, race-condition

I have a table-driven test and init var(`worker`) outside table loop. I run the test with `go test -raсe` and added `t.Parallel()` and no race condition was detected. Can I assume that my test free of `race condition`:

```
//This mock could be in a separate file.
type mockWorker struct {
}
// implment our Worker iterface
func(md mockWorker)Work()error{
    return nil
}
type mockDoer struct{
    Error  error 
    Worker worker
}
// implment our Doer iterface
func(md mockDoer)Do()error{
    if err := md.Worker.Work(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return md.Error 
}

func TestBusinessDoer(t *testing.T){
    t.Parallel()
    worker := mockWorker{}
    cases := []struct{
        Name string
        ExpectError bool 
        Error error
    }{
        {
            Name:"test does business logic",
            ExpectError : false,
            Error : nil,
        },
        {
            Name:"test fails when dependency errors",
            ExpectError : true,
            Error : errors.New("an error"),
        },
    }

    for _,td := range cases{
        t.Run(td.Name, func (t *testing.T){
            doer := mockDoer{Error: td.Error, Worker: worker}
            err := mything.BusinessDoer(doer) 
            if td.ExpectError && err == nil{
                t.Fatalf("expected an error but got none")
            } 
            if ! td.ExpectError && err != nil{
                t.Fatalf("did not expect an error but got one %s ", err.Error())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted in the answer, you need to put the `t.Parallel()` the subtest. The code you've shown doesn't have a race, but it also doesn't really do anything at all, so it's not going to prove the actual implementation.

Comment: "Can I assume that my test free of race condition" - no, even if the tests properly exercise parallelism. The race detector detects if a potential race condition occurs over the course of an execution. Due to the nature of concurrent code, there may be a potential race condition that happens to have not been exercised over the course of the test - it might be caught on subsequent runs, it might not. The race detector can provide proof positive of a race condition but never proof there there are none.

Comment: thank you, now I understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to run the sub tests in parallel.

Can you call t.Parallel() inside the subtests and check ?

```
td := td
t.Run(td.Name, func (t *testing.T){
            t.Parallel()
            doer := mockDoer{Error: td.Error, Worker: worker}
            err := mything.BusinessDoer(doer) 
            if td.ExpectError && err == nil{
                t.Fatalf("expected an error but got none")
            } 
            if ! td.ExpectError && err != nil{
                t.Fatalf("did not expect an error but got one %s ", err.Error())
            }
        })
```

Some links to refer to make it parallel:
https://gist.github.com/posener/92a55c4cd441fc5e5e85f27bca008721
https://rakyll.org/parallelize-test-tables/

Comment: still no race detected

Comment: race detector does not give a false positive. You shouldn't assume that there are no race conditions though. It just means that it didn't occur during this run of tests. It also depends on how well the tests are covering the cases.